# Spring Data - Map external resources

Tags: spring, spring-data, hateoas

I'm trying to use the RestResource annotation to avoid creating RestControllers for simple CRUD actions, but I'm facing a limitation:

If I have a simple class like :

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    String title;
    Long publisherId;

}
```

and a repository like:

```
@RestResource(path = "book", rel = "book")
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long>{
}
```

How can I map the publisher to an external resource? like :
http://www.foo.com/publisher/1

Comment: As far as I understand, you don't have `Publisher` entity but just long id. What do you expect to see by following the link you provided?

Comment: I want to use the id to map that to an url